# Fullcalendar jquery plugin recurring event day/week number in month

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to display the menu of a refectory by the plugin FullCalendar.
The menu should be something like that:

- 1st monday of month: pizza
- 2nd monday of month: pasta
- 3rd monday of month: hamburger
- 4th monday of month: beef
- 5th monday of month: soup
- 1st tuesday of month: fish and chips
- 2nd tuesday of month: potatos
- 3rd tuesday of month: ...

etc..

I need to recurring event in this way.. But I don't know if it's possible and how implement it.. I'm so confused.

At the moment my code will look something like that:

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        { start: new Date(y, m, 1), title: 'Pasta all\'olio e parmigiano' },
        { start: new Date(y, m, 2), title: 'Pasta all\'olio e parmigiano' },
        ...
```

Is there a way to set the correct date and recurring in Fullcalendar as I need, using javascript date() function, or by mixing with another technologies (PHP/MySQL..)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two options:

1. Create a Google Calendar, which supports this kind of recurring events, and add it to fullcalendar as shown [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/google_calendar/):

   ```html
   <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
               events: 'http://www.google.com/your_feed_url/'
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```
2. Calculate the event on dates your own, as fullcalendar doesn't support recurring events. You can use the [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) library as a little help:

   ```html
   <script type='text/javascript' src='date.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
       function getRecurrences(date, count) {
           var nthOccurence = Math.ceil((date.getDate() - date.getDay()) / 7),
               dates = [date];

           for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               var nextDate = dates[dates.length - 1].clone().addMonths(1);
               nextDate.moveToNthOccurrence(date.getDay(), nthOccurence);
               dates.push(nextDate);
           }

           return dates;
       }

       var date = new Date(2013, 8, 18); // 3rd Wednesday
       var nextThreeOccurences = getRecurrences(date, 3);
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much Jan!
I opted for first solution rather than the second because it seemed faster to implement.
I had to import an ICS file in Google, otherwise I could not properly handle the 5th day of the month (Google allows you to define the 1st, 2nd.. 4th and the last .. But this leads to a conflict between the 4th and the last on some month).

In the ICS file I've done something like this:
DTSTART; VALUE = DATE: 20121001
RRULE: FREQ = MONTHLY; INTERVAL = 1; BYDAY = 1MO;

The end result is what you can see on this page:
http://www.apiccolipassi.net/pasti/

Comment: Glad you got it working. And really nice website by the way. Looks great.

Comment: @deste hey did you achieve recurring event in fullCalender? i also try to do the same thing. but the problem is am new to rails and jquery. so i dont knw how to do it

Comment: @AnitaShalu Oh my God... Before working properly.. But I discover through your message that this is no longer working now. :-(
Something must have changed in Google Calendar that does not allow the library to work. I have to inquire about it..

Comment: @deste ok no problem...but pls help me if u find solution

Comment: @AnitaShalu ..Of 'course Anita! I'll give it a look as soon as possible, then I will update that post

Comment: @AnitaShalu Ok.. I must fix my website jquery and FullCalendar configuration yet (css and events click behavior), but now it works fine. The problem was an update of Google API's.. I have updated jQuery and FullCalendar plugin and config Google Developers Console (read this: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar ). So.. How can I try to help you, now that I get the control of this plugin again? :-D
If you want we can chat here on stackoverflow.. Maybe it's better than talk here, in comments :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73767/discussion-between-deste-and-anita-shalu).

Comment: @deste pls come to our chat room...want to ask u doubts